# How to monitor the memory consumed by a process?

Tags: 12.04, monitor, memory-usage

I have a process that I would like to see how much memory it consumes while it is running.

Right now I do this:

```
ps faux | grep casper
```

But that just gives me the information of that moment. It would be nice to see that value changing as the script proceeds.

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 23):

**Method 1**

Run:

```
top
```

Check for the program's PID (first column), then run:

```
top -p PID
```

**Method 2**

Either paste this into the terminal or save it as a mem_usage.sh and run it from terminal.

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
    clear
    ps faux | grep casper
    sleep 1s
done
```

Comment: How can you change it from showing %? *Out of interest :-)*

Comment: I get this when running the script: bash: ./memory_usage.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: Bah! I have edited it! Should have checked it properly before posting. The first line should say where to run it from /bin/bash (I had bin/bash so it was checking locally in a folder called bin for bash)

Comment: @ wilf
ps faux | grep casper | awk '{print $11}  {print $6}'
That should give you on one line the program name and the next the real memory size in kB.

Answer (score 8):

To monitor only your process you can check `/proc/PID/status or /proc/PID/statm`.

**About `/proc/PID/statm`:**

After doing `cat /proc/PID/statm` you should see this:

```
611450 185001 883 18 0 593431 0
```

Explanation:

1. size :- total program size (611450 X 4096/1024 = 2445800kB = 2388M)
2. resident :- resident set size (185001 X 4096/1024 = 740004kB = 722M)
3. share :- shared pages (883 X 4096 = 3532)
4. trs :- text (code) (18 X 4096/1024 = 72kB = VmExe )
5. drs :- data/stack
6. lrs :- library (593431 X 4096/1024 = 2373724kB = VmData +VmStk)
7. dt :- dirty pages

Also you can log the memory activity for your process doing a loop using `date` and `cat`.

Answer (score 5):

you could use use `top`

```
man top
```

This program allows you to sort the resource usage by, amongst others, RSS, VSZ, CPU, etc...  It's very useful.

Alternatively, for a more detailed breakdown of memory usage, try 'pmap'

```
man pmap
```

Example usage:

```
pmap -x 1234
```

Comment: With `pmap -x PID`, did you mean incredibly detailed usage :-)

Comment: indeed - can never have enough detail :)

Comment: On mine (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS) "pmap -x" with the PID doesn't show anything other than the PID and the command.  -X does the same.

Answer (score 4):

Open System Monitor, and go to the <kbd>Processes</kbd> tab:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
watch 'ps faux | grep -v grep | grep casper'
```

You may also change refresh interval using the `--interval <seconds>` parameter.

Comment: You don't need the -v grep if you change the final one to grep [c]asper. That matches casper but not itself.